# How would I enter multiple inputs into a vector with only one line of input?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, input, integer

How would I enter multiple integers in one line into a vector in C++? Like:

> Please enter integers: 1 2 3 4 5

Would the code look like:

```
vector<int> intV;
cout << "Please enter integers: ";
cin >> intV;
```

Comment: @TheCoxer Use a loop like: `while(cin >> num) { intV.push_back(num); }`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Answers go down here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ;)

Comment: @TheCoxer Alternatively you could provide an overloaded `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, std::vector<int>&)`

Comment: @flatmouse There's no single answer, but too many possible solutions for the problem.

Comment: Another idea is to use `getline`, `istringstream`, `istream_iterator` and range constructor, but it is an overkill in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could overload the `operator>>` as follows to do this if you really wanted.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& _is, std::vector<int>& _vec) {
    int data;
    while (_is >> data)
        _vec.push_back(data);
    return _is;
}
```

Or more flexibly,

```
template<typename _Ty> std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& _is, std::vector<_Ty>& _vec) {
    _Ty data;
    while (_is >> data)
        _vec.push_back(data);
    return _is;
}
```

Comment: It must be noted that this operator extracts integers until EOF (or the first "bad" character is found), not until the end of the line. To perform according to what OP said you have first to do a `getline`, put the result in an `istringstream` and only then use this operator.